# Cannot call methods on tooltip prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'destroy' : Yii2 bundle with lobipanel

Tags: jquery, yii2

I am so interested this plugin on jquery : [lobipanel](https://github.com/arboshiki/lobipanel)

I am confused to use this as bundle to all page in Yii2.
It's said to use this :

```
$(function(){
    $('.panel').lobiPanel({
        //Options go here
        ...
    });
});
```

What the best practice to use this ?

Please advise.

**Update**

```
use yii\web\AssetBundle;

/**
   * @author Qiang Xue <qiang.xue@gmail.com>
   * @since 2.0
*/
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{

public $basePath = '@webroot';
public $baseUrl = '@web';
public $sourcePath = '@bower';
public $css = [
    'css/site.css',
    'plugins/lobipanel-dist/dist/css/lobipanel.css'
];
public $js = [
    'js/moment.js',
    'plugins/lobipanel-dist/dist/js/lobipanel.js',
    'js/main.js',
];
public $depends = [

    'yii\web\YiiAsset',
    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset',
    'yii\jui\JuiAsset',
];

}
```

Got Error : Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on tooltip prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'destroy'

Comment: seems that is only javascript so you should add in a proper asset

Comment: Strangely, I have include them, and load successfully, but the panel not change. Please see update

Answer (score 2):

Try changing order of

```
public $js = [
   'js/moment.js',
   'plugins/lobipanel-dist/dist/js/lobipanel.js',
   'js/main.js',
];
```

to:

```
 public $js = [
   'js/main.js',
   'js/moment.js',
   'plugins/lobipanel-dist/dist/js/lobipanel.js',
];
```

Reference from here: [1] ['cannot call methods on tooltip prior to initialization' error when I add the jquery-ui library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35690989/cannot-call-methods-on-tooltip-prior-to-initialization-error-when-i-add-the-jq)

Comment: NOt work, cause in main.js is the lobi panel is decalare init to lobipanel

Answer (score 0):

There is conflict between Jui and lobipanel tooltips. Did you use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/